# Make vertical Chart into a horizontal chart CSS3

Tags: html, css, styles

I am trying to convert a horizontal chart into a vertical chart. I have run into an issue though. I can't get the lines connected to the box to appear in the middle when I change the code to be horizontal. I am able to have the boxes appear horizontally.

**[Orignal Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/Jeferson-Natanael/pen/EEvPpQ)**

My code:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="boxplot">
      <tr height="40">
        <td class="line boxplot-max"></td>
        <td class="boxplot-max"></td>
        <td class="boxplot-q3" colspan="4"></td>
        <td class="boxplot-mdn" colspan="4"></td>
        <td class="line boxplot-q1"></td>
        <td class="boxplot-q1"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9h7zv4c5/2/)**

Comment: "Appear in the middle"? Are they supposed to be horizontal and vertically centered?

Comment: @isherwood yes just like the veritcal demo in codepen

Comment: You'll need more markup. You can't center a table cell vertically. Does every element need to be a table component?

Comment: @isherwood it could be in divs if not in a table